# Telegram bot inline search doesn't work for custom gif URLs

Tags: python, bots, telegram, gif

The `InlineQueryResultArticle` API does not work correctly when we pass a custom URL (the URL of gig which is on my own server). 
I mean when the search bar opens, it says "No Results".

However, when I pass a gif from a famous website like giphy, it works correctly!

Does anyone know about this issue?

```py
InlineQueryResultGif(
id = str(uuid4()),
title = "giff",                                                 
gif_url = "https://media0.giphy.com/media/kA5Gnnr2bcEIzu26DT/giphy.gif",
thumbnail_url = "https://media0.giphy.com/media/kA5Gnnr2bcEIzu26DT/giphy.gif"
)
```

I tried everything I could, searched a lot, used other similar APIs but they didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Telegram Desktop was the issue and did not show the correct results!
My time just got wasted!